# How do I unpromoted existing node when new node is promoted to front page (Programatically)?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

In Drupal 8 I want only one node at a time to be promoted to front page. If user promoted new node the existed should un-promoted automatically.

Can we implement this with events in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 3):

The settings for `FrontPage` is provided by default in Drupal 8. Because the `Frontpage` in Drupal 8 is a View, so it opens all kind of setting feasibility.

Hence if you go at `Admin/structures/views` you will find a view named `FrontPage`.

Hence, you **just need to change the Pager setting. Change `item 10` to `item 1`**.

And in sort criteria It is already `Content: Author on (desc)`, so it will automatically will show new item first. So as you publish new item it will replaced and you have set `item 1` in pager, so only 1 item will be shown on front page which is latest one.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but my question is how I achieve this programmatically (we have some complex multilingual logic on site). I was wondering may be it's possible with Drupal 8 events. One solution could be implement `hook_presave` or `hook_update_node` etc and check if `promotion` is selected remove old promoted node and `buildView` for front page with new promoted node. Thinking how do  implement this with new DRUPAL 8 EVENTS  if possible.

Comment: But my friend, you did not specify in your question regarding doing this  programmatically..:) All answerer first takes a pure drupal UI approach. If not then they suggest whether code or module. Anyway, I also learned something from your question, so thanks. For programmatically, I will think and if found out I will add update in answer. I suggest you to add update in your question, about complexity and want to achieve programmatically, so others will get better idea.

Comment: The question was obviously asking for a programmatic solution. It says that the node should be unpromoted "automatically", which means that it isn't being done manually in the UI. It also asks how to implement the desired behavior using events, which are an inherently programmatic concept.